# UAT is best performed in which environment? production or QA environment?

Tags: uat

Which is the best environment to do business testing on ? Prod or QA.

Thanks
Rasnai

Answer (score 2):

Ideally, you should have three environments; dev, test and live.

Your development should be developer tested on dev and then released to test for testing against a test case of expected functionality.

Your live environment should be a mirror of the last tested and approved release on test.

You should perform UAT on test and then, once approved, release from test to live.

(Credentials - Almost 20 years as a software tester, project manager and hobbyist developer).

Answer (score 0):

Tests on prod? :) That tests should be done on separate env. like QA, with data as close as possible to real. That way user can try the system, but with out triggering real actions.

That is a bit tricky. Usually they (I mean users, testers) do have sets of sample data for cases they need to test. The more real that sets are the better.